# Can "for" be interchangeable with "since" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice

"For I do not know his name yet, I will acknowledge my new friend as James for now."

Also, is the word "acknowledge" suitable in this sentence?

Thanks!

(I'm trying to not use the word "since" here because I have already used it)

Answer (score 2):

It has to be *since*. *For* cannot be used to introduce a dependent clause starting a sentence, as you do here. *For* is a coordinating conjunction and is used to connect two independent clauses. For example:

> She spent Christmas alone, for she had nowhere else to go.

Note that the use of *for* as a conjunction meaning *since* or *because* " ... *is declining*. ... *This usage now seems rather literary*" (Peters in *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage*, p214).

*Acknowledge* is not the best word here. My suggestion:

> Since I do not know his name yet, I will *call* my new friend James for
>   now.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I just forgot to mention that I'm not trying to use "since"

Comment: @DDXTWE, subordinating conjunctions _because_ and _as_ both work here in place of _since_,

Comment: "Acknowledge" means that you will call your friend "James" to his face. If you are just using the name so you don't have to keep saying, "My new friend," use "call" or, more specifically, "refer to".